# C: what is the second # for in #define FOO(s) #s

Tags: c

What does # do in C? Especially in #define like this

```
#define FOO(s) #s
```

Comment: It's the "stringizing operator", available only during preprocessor macro substitution.

Comment: @Michal Canecky: What does your favorite C book say about it?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx):

> The number-sign or "stringizing" operator (#) converts macro
>   parameters to string literals without expanding the parameter
>   definition. It is used only with macros that take arguments. If it
>   precedes a formal parameter in the macro definition, the actual
>   argument passed by the macro invocation is enclosed in quotation marks
>   and treated as a string literal. The string literal then replaces each
>   occurrence of a combination of the stringizing operator and formal
>   parameter within the macro definition.

The page linked above contains some practical examples for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a string so

```
#define FOO(s) #s
FOO(hello)
```

Is the same as

```
"hello"
```